# Select rectangle area from vector layer on qgsmapcanvas

Tags: qgis, c++, qt

I have created simple Qt project (C++) to load the vector layer on map Canvas. You can find the layer in QGISTest03_MapData Folder. I have attached the project link below. I want to select a rectangle area from the vector layer with mouse events. Any suggestion or code will help.

https://github.com/Bharath8350/QtGis.git

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    mapCanvas = new QgsMapCanvas();

    // Create a vector layer
    QString vectorFilePath = "/home/rapl/Bharath/CABS/Reference Docs/MapData/IND_adm/IND_adm1.shp";        //! India State Border Map
    QString baseName = QFileInfo(vectorFilePath).baseName();
    QgsVectorLayer *vectorLayer = new QgsVectorLayer(vectorFilePath, baseName, "ogr");

    // Check if the layer was loaded successfully
    if (!vectorLayer->isValid())
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(nullptr, "Error", "Failed to load vector layer!");
    }

    // Refresh the map
    mapCanvas->setDestinationCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem::fromEpsgId(4326));

    // Add the layer to the map
    QgsProject::instance()->addMapLayer(vectorLayer);
    mapCanvas->setExtent(vectorLayer->extent());
    layers.append(vectorLayer);
    mapCanvas->setLayers(QList<QgsMapLayer*>() << layers);

    mapCanvas->freeze(false);
    mapCanvas->refresh();
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(mapCanvas, 1, 0, 1, 2);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```